# TypeError using Typescript abstract class

Tags: typescript, types, abstract-class

I was trying to abstract code with Typescript and I ended up encountering a strange case that gives a TypeError at runtime.

```js
abstract class TestAbstract {
  abstract execute(p: { word: string }): { name: string };
}

class TestImplementation {
  execute(p: {
    word: string,
    age: number
  }): {
    name: string
    email: string
  } {
    console.log('TestImplementation - execute', p)

    p.age.toExponential() // Will raise TypeError

    return {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: ''
    }
  }
}

function myfunc (c: TestAbstract) {
  c.execute({ word: '000.000.000-00' })
}

myfunc(new TestImplementation()) // Why typescript does not complain about the difference between signatures?
```

My tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

I've try using interfaces instead of abstract class
Also, i've try using the "implements" or "extends" keywords

In all cases, nothing changed. The compiler doesn't complain about the different signatures

Comment: Methods are checked bivariantly, which is unsafe but intentional. You could switch to function-prop syntax in your class maybe as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0OlRN).  See the other q/a for more info.